# Filtering by days in the week without time (Realm & Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, nspredicate

I'm using Realm database where each item has a date and I need arrays where each array contains items for that day of the current week. But I can not figure out the correct query parameters.

I want to only be able to get items based on the day it's for, for example: the today array will contain items with today's date and times sometime between today at 12am to 11:59pm.

What I have so far is the code below which gets the events that have dates before today at the specific time of checking this line.:

`var events = realm.objects(Event.self)
 var today = events?.filter("date < %@", Date())`

**How can I get the filters to work to arrays filtered by each day of this week?**

I'm thinking maybe something like: `var tomorrow = events?.filter("date > %@ && date < %@", tomorrow_at_12am, tomorrow_at_1159pm)` may work but I am not sure how to get dates with those specific day and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
let realmObj = Realm()    
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Start >= %@ AND End <= %@", start,end)
let results = realmObj.objects(Event.self).filter(predicate)
```

Comment: How can I make the date for the range? For example the `specificNSDate` for the first date slot be Tomorrow's date (month/day/year) at 12:00am and the date for the second spot be Tomorrow's date (month/day/year) at 11:59pm. So I can get all of the items that are only on tomorrow's date

Comment: Answer updated, please try now. Make sure you get valid start and end value in log. Check with breakpoints.

Comment: Worked perfectly. For anyone who looks at this I used this website to make the dates http://ios-tutorial.com/working-dates-swift/